# go there vs go up there

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

What is the difference between 'go up there' and 'go there'?

Examples:

> - The boys want to go up there.
> - He didn't want to go there.

Are they interchangeable in the above examples?

Comment: Sometimes they mean the same thing, and sometimes they do not. In what context do you find these sentences?

Comment: I just found a couple of examples for a question. Originally I got stuck when I was translating the following sentence: "We had heard this story about lost gold from a Gold Rush-era robbery, and we wanted to go up there.". But there was no mention about "up" or "north" before. And I was misunderstood why there was used "go up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Up" should indicate that the *place to go* is spatially higher than where [the boy] is currently located.  Given that, they can be used interchangeably

Comment: thank you, Alexandria. I also added an extra comment to my question, can you review it?

Comment: I would need more context from the text you are quoting - but my guess is that location of the lost gold is in an elevated area.  Perhaps this is a story about The Lost Dutchman's gold, in the Superstition Mountains of Arizona?

Comment: I don't know may I paste here links or not. I just was watching video and reading transcript from here http://www.ted.com/talks/david_lang_my_underwater_robot.html (There is a button "show transcript" in order to see full transcript of this video)

Comment: Look at the previous sentence: "my friend Eric and I decided we wanted to explore this underwater cave in the foothills of the Sierras."  The subject regards *the cave*, which is in a mountain (Sierras).  Even if the speaker is located in a place which has a similar elevation, the mountain would still be considered 'up' since you have to ascend to it from the base of the mountain.